# Phone Number Detection Issues

Tags: blackberry, detection, phone-number

In my BB app, i want to detect phone numbers as well as to call those phone numbers. In order to do that i have used [ActiveRichTextField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ActiveRichTextField.html) instead of [LabelField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/LabelField.html). This field works fine to detect the phone numbers but the problem i am getting is that it **fails to detect some of the numbers** especially of the country Australia. It detects phone numbers of `India` perfectly fine but not for `Australia` and some other numbers. What i have done for this is posted below as:

```java
ActiveRichTextField descField;
if (isFocaseble) {
    descField = new ActiveRichTextField(replacedString.trim(),
                                        ActiveRichTextField.FIELD_LEFT |
                                        ActiveRichTextField.USE_ALL_WIDTH |
                                        ActiveRichTextField.FOCUSABLE)
```

i have checked here if its focused or not because only numbers have to be gained focused since there are other data also which have no need to be given focus and `replacedString` is what the data getting from the webservice.Below are the snaps of my screen through which one can get the clear idea of my problem.

(1) **Below are Numbers of Australia**:

[image]

(2) **Numbers of Australia**

[image]

(3) **Numbers of India**

[image]

Can anybody have any idea regarding this? why i am not able to detect whole numbers and where am i lacking?

Any sort of help would be appreciable.

Comment: ContactList contactList; 
 
 contactList = (ContactList) PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);
 Enumeration items = contactList.items();
 ////System.out.println("Contacts information:............................"+contactList.items());
 while (items.hasMoreElements())
 {
  contact = (BlackBerryContact) items.nextElement(); // here contact is custom class contain emailID,name,contact etc
 
  int cntTel = contact.countValues(BlackBerryContact.TEL);
 }

Comment: If you remove whitespaces does it recognize better?

Comment: i have also tried by removing whitespaces @EugenMartynov, but the case didn't solved.There also numbers with whitesapces between them but are been detected correctly but the rest dont.